# How to traverse through DOM object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like this. How to traverse to `<br>` tag using `jQuery`?

Condition:

1. should not use class attributes.
2. should not use split method.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
hello
     </div>
123
<br>
paragraphs
<br>
escapes
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For me, only option is to traverse using `<br>` tag,
 so how can I loop through `<br>` and get next data after `<br>`.

I tried Like this getting the `HTML`, but unable to loop through using `<br>`.

```
var html=$(body).html();
```

Output I need:
        "escapes"

Can you please help me to traverse through `<br>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texts you are seeking are not within their own tags. They are referred to as text-nodes, and jQuery doesn't have a simple way to grab them. But you can use a little raw JavaScript with your jquery to do so.

In this example the script grabs all of the text-nodes inside the outer-div (`contents()` grabs every type of child node, then `filter` on `nodeType==3` grabs just the text-nodes), and loops through them, alerting each:

```
$('body > div').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    })
    .each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());}
    );
```

You'll see that it finds the white-spaces just inside the outer-div before the paragraph and after the last line-break (the alert is empty for the first and last text-nodes) but also finds each piece of text between the `<br>`s

Comment: when i tried above method. in alert i'm getting only empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('br').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Check the following link for more info:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Hope it helps.

Comment: PS: Do no forget to accept the answer if you find the answer useful ;)

Comment: line-breaks don't have values (Or text). The OP needs to either wrap the text in their own markup (as Pranav suggests), or grab the text-nodes (as I suggest).