# Change cursor to pointer on hover plain text like <a>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to imitate a link in the text of the table cells, changing the cursor to pointer on hover. Is really easy, I know.

But it does not work the way I want.

Considering this CSS

> .pointerCursor{cursor:pointer;}

If I use the following jQuery...

```
$("table tbody td").hover(
    function(){$(this).addClass('pointerCursor');},
    function(){$(this).removeClass('pointerCursor');}
);
```

...obviously the cursor is changed to the pointer in each entire cell box and therefore, the entire table.

Is there a jQuery selector that allows me to change the cursor when hover **only the text** in a cell, imitating an `<a>` link, so that the rest of the table remains the default cursor?

Comment: do you have _only_ text in each `td`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to wrap the text in something - you can't target text content directly.

You can use jQuery to get the text nodes as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794538/1901857) and then [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) them in `span`s with your class:

```js
$('td').contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span class="pointerCursor" />');
```

```css
td {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.pointerCursor{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 1</td>
        <td>Text 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this via pure CSS:

```
table tbody td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please comment if you need a pure JavaScript solution

Edit:
After re-reading your question, I think what you're looking for is changing the cursor on cells that aren't empty?

```
td:hover:not(:empty) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not on entire cell, but only on the text in the cell. Thanks anyway!